# Angular2 form page reloads?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-forms

I am using Angular2

unable to figure out why page is refereshing:

My Form:

```
<form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Username</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Email" name="username" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
                        </div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" (click)=onSubmit() />


                    </form>
```

In Ts:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
```

declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'cat-page',
  templateUrl: './login-alpha.html'
})

export class PagesLoginAlpha{

```
onSubmit()
{
    console.log("in submittt");
}
```

}

Comment: put quotes on click function `(click)="onSubmit()"`

Comment: No now also its reloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type to button

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" (click)="onSubmit()" />
```

Or use button

```
<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()">submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying now page is not reloading thanks a lot again, but I have an issue my issue is that I am applying jQuery validation and to  apply validation I need form to be submitted for that I used type submit. In my case (ngSubmit) is also not working can you please help .. Thanks in advance

Comment: instead using jquery validation using angular validation

Comment: Yes agree but actually I am preferring a theme which already uses that validation and I am in need to keep them, this is the reason. Do you have any idea how I can achieve it with type submit, bocoz only then that validation will work.

Comment: you going use only the template right if you're going use angular go with angular validation which will be easy